# Connection Timeout Expired ... [Pre-Login] initialization=211; handsake=14787;

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have to add "service based database" in my visual studio 2017 community, but i found this message:
[image]
"Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=211; handshake=14787;"
can anyone tell me what i must to do?

Answer (score 0):

The “Connection Timeout expired” error commonly occurs in the following cases:

- An instance of the SQL Server Database Engine is not running.
- The SQL Server Browser service is not running.
- The TCP/IP is disabled.
- The server name was typed incorrectly.
- There are network problems.
- The TCP/IP port for the Database Engine instance is blocked by a firewall.
- The client and server are not configured to use the same network protocol.

this link might help you, [Connection Timeout expired](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/30/connection-timeout-expired-pre-login-handshake/)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had same issue. It was Network issue. Firewall was dropping the packets in application level. We have able to access Ip and port by telnet ok, but does not  by any SQL Client. Please contact your network administrator